# grouping one column and leaving other constants in there

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

How can I change the group function in the code below to also include the constant value of `startdate`?

```
#Reproducing an example of what I like to have: 
employee <- c('John Doe','John Doe','Peter Gynn','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','Jolie Hope')
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2007-3-14'))
salary <- c(100,200,100,300,800,12)
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, startdate, salary)

#Grouping by employee en summing salary
grouped.file <- employ.data %>% group_by(employee) %>%
  summarize(salary = sum(salary, na.rm =T))

#But I would like to have a dataframe like this: 
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
salary <- c(300,400,812)
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, startdate, salary)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `startdate` is constant you can use it in `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)

employ.data %>%  
    group_by(employee, startdate) %>% 
    summarize(salary = sum(salary, na.rm =TRUE))

#  employee   startdate  salary
#  <fct>      <date>      <dbl>
#1 John Doe   2010-11-01    300
#2 Jolie Hope 2007-03-14    812
#3 Peter Gynn 2008-03-25    400
```

Or get its `first` value in `summarize`

```
employ.data %>%  
 group_by(employee) %>% 
 summarize(startdate = first(startdate), salary = sum(salary, na.rm =TRUE))
```

Or use `mutate` and select only 1st (any) row in each group.

```
employ.data %>% 
  group_by(employee) %>%
  mutate(salary = sum(salary, na.rm =TRUE)) %>%
  slice(1L)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. How can I modify the first to sum also another column in addition to salary?

Comment: @Afke If you have multiple columns to sum, use `summarise_at` something like : `employ.data %>%  
  group_by(employee, startdate) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(salary, another_col), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two base R approaches to make it:

- Using `aggregate()`

```
employ.data <- aggregate(salary ~ employee + startdate, employ.data,FUN = function(x) sum(x,na.rm = T))
```

which gives

```
> employ.data
    employee  startdate salary
1 Jolie Hope 2007-03-14    812
2 Peter Gynn 2008-03-25    400
3   John Doe 2010-11-01    300
```

- Using `ave()` and `unique()`

```
unique(within(employ.data, salary <- ave(salary,employee,startdate,FUN = function(x) sum(x,na.rm = T))))
```

which gives

```
> employ.data
    employee  startdate salary
1   John Doe 2010-11-01    300
3 Peter Gynn 2008-03-25    400
5 Jolie Hope 2007-03-14    812
```